# forward lookup zone not affecting domain network computers

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, internal-dns

ok so on the internet we have companyname.com which is our website and DNS for it hosted elsewhere. here at office our windows domain is companyname.office.

On the internet I have a A record for a subdomain that points to a IP on a server here I exposed. so on the outside network I can type ping subdomain.companyname.com and it returns the IP that I have exposed here and I can connect and everything is glorious.

However.....

Inside the office we have laptops that come and go.  So when on the office network I need the subdomain.companyname.com to resolve to a different IP than it does out on the internet.

So i did what has always worked and I added a forward lookup zone on out domain controller in the office. I then created an A record for subdomain.companyname.com and then pointed it to the internal IP address of the server.

so here is the annoying thing... On the DC machines in the office I can ping subdomain.companyname.com and it returns the proper internal IP address and pings back. But, on any other machine in the building it resolved to the external IP and will not return a ping.

Yes, DNS server have had caches cleared and clients have had flushdns run on them before trying to ping.

Please advise as this is Oh so frustrating.

servers are Win2k8R2 clients are win7,win8, and some macs.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "On the DC machines in the office"? Do you mean that the internal IP is returned if you do the test on a domain controller, but on any of the workstations it will return the external IP?

Comment: One thing that's worth noting is that if you create a forward lookup zone for "company.com" on your internal server, then the internal server is going to think it knows the answer for [anything].company.com. That means that if you have other records (say www.company.com or mail.company.com) that you want to resolve using the public DNS, that won't work internally. As a workaround, you can create a zone just for subdomain.company.com internally.